# how to know current java VM version

Tags: java, jvm

I updated my java VM to v8. But still my command promt shows version is 1.8 and i am unable to run java commands in PC. What is the exact issue ? give me some suggestions to rectify this.....

Comment: Java 8 ***is*** java 1.8...

Comment: Or java 1.8 is java v8.

Comment: Just googling Java 1.8 will give you links to Java 8 (showing you they are the same...)

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 and 1.8 mean the same thing.   If `java -version` reports `1.8.0`, then you are using Java 8.  So there is no issue: nothing to rectify.

---

The official word on version numbers and names for Java 8 is in this Oracle document:

- [Java Platform, Standard Edition 8 Names and Versions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk8-naming-2157130.html).